# What is the solution for this type of error message "IndexError"?

Tags: python-3.x, file, io

i tried to write a little program to open a text file and read some lines.
I used a for loop for that purpose, but,the program doesn't work.
It displays this message : "IndexError: list index out of range".
What is the issue? how to esolve it ?

Here is the code :

```
f=open("C:\\Users\\grami\\Desktop\\python.txt", "rt")
for i in range(3):
    print(f.readlines()[i])
            

f.close()
```

By using only the command " readlines() ", I had a list containing the lines as elements of the list.
I wanted to show every element a part.
So, I used a FOR loop.
But, it didn't work.

Comment: You are reading the file 3 times (which is inefficient) and then printing line 0, 1, and 2. How many lines does the file have? It must have 3 lines for this code to work.

Comment: Can you share the first 10 lines of your `python.txt` file?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.
Here is the file text: 
" 

How to use python IDLE

How to Install Anaconda.

How to use Jupyter notebook(Ipython).

What the difference between Variables & Operators.

Operators Types.

Python Data Types.

Lambda Expression.

String Functions & entries in Python.".

Comment: It's empty? In that case, how do you expect being able to print the 3rd line of an empty file?